# Reload application

Tags: ios, swift

I need to reload the application's main view. As far as I know, iOS does not have the ability to close and run the application again.
Is it therefore possible to:
a) return to the splash screen of the application and load the main view of the application or
b) just reload the view of the main application?

Comment: Just reset your app's rootView Controller that should do the job. No need to individually pop out each VC if you have written code carefully enough to ensure deinit gets called on all these VCs when you reset the VC and set a new instance of MainVC as your rootVC, all other VCs on top should be deinited

Comment: how can I rootVC deinit?

Comment: You thing about something like this: func deinitMainVC(){
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard? = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView")
            
            delegate.window?.rootViewController = rootController
        }
    } ?

Comment: yup :) Thats wat I meant. When u do that your earlier rootVC should be deinited and along with it entire view hierarchy